# Django cache arbitrary query results

Tags: sql, django, django-models, query-optimization

In a certain Django view, I query a large amount of complex data. I make no changes to any data in this view.

It would be convenient if Django simply cached all database queries in this view to reduce duplicate queries. I can cache intermediate results by hand, but due to the complexity of the project this would be painstaking and require significant restructuring.[1]

Is there simply a way—like a function decorator—to tell Django to cache all database queries during a specific context?

[1] If the query were fully optimized, I suspect it would take less 300ms, so the chance the data changes during the query is small. Even if it did, minor inconsistencies are acceptable in the application.